# How do I put two ## (#toolbar=0 and #view=fitH) after one src?

Tags: html, iframe, view, toolbar, src

This is my Code I'm talking about:
`<iframe src="/test/test.pdf#view=fitH" width="100%" height="1000px"></iframe>`
So it works, however how do I make now still #toolbar=0 to it?

Kind regards
Matthew

Answer (score 1):

you can use '&' to add more. So your code should look like this

```
<iframe src="/test/test.pdf#view=FitH&toolbar=0" width="100%" height="1000px"></iframe>
```